# Why aren't scripts in ~/.pyenv/versions/*/bin callable from the command line?

Tags: python, setuptools, pyenv

I recently installed pyenv in order to switch between several competing python interpreters on a per-project basis.  As such, `python setup.py develop` placed `console_script` entry points in `~/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/bin`.  However, calling one of these scripts from the command line (e.g.:  `$ my_entry_point_script`) results in an error:  the command is not found.

How can I fix this issue?  Is this a problem with `$PATH`, `$PTHONPATH`, something else?  For reference, my shell (fish) executes `status --is-interactive; and . (pyenv init -lpsub)` on startup.

**Edit:**  a correct solution will maintain a clean seperation between various versions of python.

Answer (score 5):

To make the binaries work you need to run

```
pyenv rehash
```

From the pyenv help

```
pyenv rehash - Rehash pyenv shims (run this after installing executables)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell your shell (probably bash?) where to look for executable programs. you can do that on the command-line (or write it into your `.bashrc` to make it permanent):

```
PATH=/new/path:"${PATH}"
```

update: in `fish` this would be:

```
set PATH /new/path $PATH
```

and to make it permanent: edit `~/.config/fish/config.fish` and write the line above in there.

this way bash/fish will find the python in your virtual-env before the one in the system. *do you really want that?*

**WARNING:** this introduces a security problem (depending on who has write-access to your virtual-env directory; a malicious version of `ls` or some other command in there could wreck your system).

or - as always - you can call your programs in there using the full path.

Comment: nice username ;)  To be clear, this is an issue with pyenv and not virtualenv, although I suspect the former uses the latter under the hood.  I just want to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: oh, my bad. but this is a general shell problem and goes for any directory containing executable files that you would be able to call.

Comment: Thats what I figured, but I thought I'd bring it up just to be safe.  Thanks for the answer -- I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: It just occurred to me that adding these paths to $PATH would defeat the purpose of pyenv, as any interpreter could call any one of these commands, so there's no longer any isolation petween py2.7 and py3.4.  I'd prefer a pyenv-specific solution, but thank you for your help, regardless!